# Objective C - show a html page without using UIWebview within application

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I show a html page without using UIWebView within application? Means it should open within the app and not as an external link to the Safari browser.

Comment: please correct your question it so confusion about what you exactly wants

Comment: I think you are confused as to what a `UIWebView` is, you can add a `UIWebView` to your application, just like you do with `UIView`/`UIImageView` etc and display your content without it actually opening up in the external `Safari` app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Display HTML with NSAttributedString

Using Webviews in your apps can be frustrating at times; even if you’re only displaying a small amount of HTML content, Webviews can consume a lot of memory. **iOS 7** makes this a lot easier, as you can create an **NSAttributedString** from **HTML** with a few lines of code, as such:

```
NSString *html = @"<bold>Wow!</bold> Now <em>iOS</em> can create <h3>NSAttributedString</h3> from HTMLs!";
NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType};

NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:options documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS 9 introduced `Safari View Controller`. [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016198-DontLinkElementID_27) URL feeds are read only, the only page that populates is the one that you specify, and it retains in-app experience. It also shares cookies with Safari. However, concerning HTML you will still have to build it as a website then populate it in `SFSafariViewController`

Prior to iOS9 you can use WKWebView, both of which are discussed in the following video which you should be reviewing anyways:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=504

Answer (score 0):

This question is fairly confusing, first you say "without using UIWebView" then you say "it should open in the app and not as an external link to the Safari browser".

However, regardless of that, in order to display a web page "in the app" you would have to use [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/), or [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/) if you can target iOS 8 and later.

Comment: Sorry if you are getting confused with the question. The thing is UIWebView takes time to load the html page on the first instance, so I am searching for the another option which can be alternate for UIWebView

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.textLbl.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:    [@"Your html-string" dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                                                                      options:@{     NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType
                                                                                 } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```